# Remove action added through function

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, actions

A theme I'm using modified a woocommerce that I'd like undo in my child theme.

It's been added as shown:

```
function theme_setup(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'mod_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
}
```

How do I remove the add_action?

I tried just using remove_action, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623

```
<?php
function child_remove_parent_function() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'mod_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'child_remove_parent_function' );
?>
```

Explanation is in the link.